# Remove loops for sentence comparison in NLP

Tags: python, numpy, bert-language-model

I'm using BERT to compare text similarity, with the following code:

```
from bert_embedding import BertEmbedding
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance  import cosine as cosine_similarity

bert_embedding = BertEmbedding()
TEXT1 = "As expected from MIT-level of course: it's interesting, challenging, engaging, and for me personally quite enlightening. This course is second part of 5 courses in  micromasters program. I was interested in learning about supply chain (purely personal interest, my work touch this topic but not directly) and stumbled upon this course, took it, and man-oh-man...I just couldn't stop learning. Now I'm planning to take the rest of the courses. Average time/effort per week should be around 8-10 hours, but I tried to squeeze everything into just 5 hours since I have very limited free time. You will need 2-3 hours per week for the lecture videos, 2 hours for practice problems, and another 2 hours for the weekly homework. This course offers several topics around demand forecasting and inventory. Basic knowledge of probability and statistics is needed. It will help if you take the prerequisite course: supply chain analytics. But if you've already familiar with basic concept of statistics, you can pick yourself along the way. The lectures are very interesting and engaging, it gives you a lot of knowledge but also throw in some business perspective, so it's very relatable and applicable! The practice problems can help strengthen the understanding of the given knowledge and the homework are very challenging compared to other online-courses I have taken. This course is the best quality I have taken so far, and I have taken several (3-4 MOOCs) from other provider."
TEXT1 = TEXT1.split('.')

sentence2 = ["CHALLENGING COURSE "]
```

from there I want to find the best match of sentence2 in one of the sentences of TEXT1, using cosine distance

```
best_match = {'sentence':'','score':''}
best = 0
for sentence in TEXT1: 
  #sentence = sentence.replace('SUPPLY CHAIN','')
  if len(sentence) < 5:
    continue
  avg_vec1 = calculate_avg_vec([sentence])
  avg_vec2 = calculate_avg_vec(sentence2)

  score = cosine_similarity(avg_vec1,avg_vec2)
  if score > best:
    best_match['sentence'] =  sentence
    best_match['score'] =  score
    best = score

best_match
```

The code is working, but since I want to compare the sentence2 not only with TEXT1 with but N texts I need to improve the speed. is it possible to vectorice this loop? or any way to speed it up?

Comment: Since order does not need to be preserved, make them both sets and compare.

Comment: @d_kennetz I'm not clear about your suggestion

Comment: Have you profiled your code ? what is taking more time ? `calculate_avg_vec` or `cosine_similarity` ?

Comment: Are you try to use parallel loop? I think it could be help because you have only sentence2 to share between threads.

Comment: I don't see where `bert_embedding` comes into your code later. What you could do is run a loop to convert your sentences into embeddings, then use sklearn's `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity` to calculate a matrix of similarities.

Comment: As you are using BERT, are you sure your system has more resources to try something in parallel, multi-threaded operation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cosine_similarity` is defined as a dot product of two normalized vectors.

This is essentially a matrix multiplication, followed by an `argmax` to get the best index.

I'll be using `numpy`, even though - as mentioned in the comments - you could probably plug it in to the `BERT` model with `pytorch` or `tensorflow`.

First, we define a **normalized** average vector:

```
def calculate_avg_norm_vec(sentence):
    vs = sentence2vectors(sentence) # TODO: use Bert embedding
    vm = vs.mean(axis=0)
    return vm/np.linalg.norm(vm)
```

Then, we build a matrix of all sentences and their vectors

```
X = np.apply_along_axis(calculate_avg_norm_vec, 1, all_sentences)
target = calculate_avg_norm_vec(target_sentence)
```

Finally, we'll need to multiply the `target` vector with the `X` matrix, and take the `argmax`

```
index_of_sentence = np.dot(X,target.T).argmax(axis=1)
```

You might want to make sure that the `axis` and indexing fit your data, but this is the overall scheme